# Why the order of the symbolic operation still holds after redefinition in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Julia we can redefine the operator like ＋,× ,sin, cos and so on. But one interesting thing is that after the redefinition the order among all those amended operators still hold,like multiplication still goes before summation no matter how you redefine your own function,why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply a function of how [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is defined for infix operators.  You can find the [precedence table](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/mathematical-operations/#operator-precedence) in the manual. Precedence defines how Julia code is parsed into a sequence of nested function calls. You can manually specify precedence with parentheses or traditional function call syntax.

You can see this happening just by asking Julia to parse (but not execute) the code. It returns back a quoted expression, which is printed in a way that mimics the standard way of writing that code in Julia. There are a number of tools that allow you to inspect this quoted expression; one that's helpful to display the nesting of calls is [`Meta.show_sexpr`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/?highlight=show_sexpr#program-representation).

```
julia> ex = parse("1 + 2 * 3")
:(1 + 2 * 3)

julia> Meta.show_sexpr(ex)
(:call, :+, 1, (:call, :*, 2, 3))
```

This is simply stating that it will multiply 2*3 before adding 1 to it.  That is entirely based upon the nested structure of the parentheses. Whatever function is bound to `*` will get executed first, regardless of its definition.  Now compare the results above with things like:

```
parse("(1 + 2) * 3")
parse("+(1, *(2, 3))")
parse("*(1, +(2, 3))")
```

Comment: can the order of precedence be altered in Julia?

Comment: [julia/src/julia-parser.scm](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a108f059cbfa8eae9e8a844c8c4bb2e06a13aa3a/src/julia-parser.scm#L1-L31)

Comment: If different parts of Julia were supposed to parse different depending on the input types (in order to make it method-dependent), it's quite easy to come up with an example where the parsing is ambiguous. Likewise, if you had a knob to just change precedence, it would be highly breaking and make it so that way relying on it in any library wouldn't be possible. I can't think of a good way to make it able to be altered, yet still retain its usability beyond small user-facing scripts.

Comment: Well, you could probably fork JuliaParser.jl and write string macros that use your own version of the parser.